# Pieces on Chess Game GUI are not visible, in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Currently I am working on a java project whereas I implement chess game rules to an existing skeleton code which provides me the chess game board and the main function. As you can see in my following code, there are two sections of it. One which is already implemented and should not be modified and another section where I should implement two functions. `actionPerformed` is a callback function that occurs when coordinates (x, y) are clicked. `onInitiateBoard` is a callback function that occurs after the Reset button is clicked. My problem here is that when I run the code literally no pieces on the chess board appears. I am a beginner in java and I am stuck with this problem for a while. Also there should be no problem importing the .img files because I saved them in the right filepath which is in the same level as the src file where my java class is. Thanks for everyone in advance and I would appreciate if someone gives me some advices how to approach such problems if I get them next time.

Edit: The GUI I am using is swing.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
//======================================================Don't modify below===============================================================//
enum PieceType {king, queen, bishop, knight, rook, pawn, none}
enum PlayerColor {black, white, none}

public class ChessBoard {
    private final JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(3, 3));
    private JPanel chessBoard;
    private JButton[][] chessBoardSquares = new JButton[8][8];
    private Piece[][] chessBoardStatus = new Piece[8][8];
    private ImageIcon[] pieceImage_b = new ImageIcon[7];
    private ImageIcon[] pieceImage_w = new ImageIcon[7];
    private JLabel message = new JLabel("Enter Reset to Start");

    ChessBoard(){
        initPieceImages();
        initBoardStatus();
        initializeGui();
        initiateBoard();
    }

    public final void initBoardStatus(){
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++) chessBoardStatus[j][i] = new Piece();
        }
    }

    public final void initPieceImages(){
        pieceImage_b[0] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/king_b.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_b[1] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/queen_b.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_b[2] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/bishop_b.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_b[3] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/knight_b.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_b[4] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/rook_b.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_b[5] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/pawn_b.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_b[6] = new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));

        pieceImage_w[0] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/king_w.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_w[1] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/queen_w.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_w[2] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/bishop_w.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_w[3] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/knight_w.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_w[4] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/rook_w.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_w[5] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/pawn_w.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        pieceImage_w[6] = new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
    }

    public ImageIcon getImageIcon(Piece piece){
        if(piece.color.equals(PlayerColor.black)){
            if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.king)) return pieceImage_b[0];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.queen)) return pieceImage_b[1];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.bishop)) return pieceImage_b[2];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.knight)) return pieceImage_b[3];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.rook)) return pieceImage_b[4];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.pawn)) return pieceImage_b[5];
            else return pieceImage_b[6];
        }
        else if(piece.color.equals(PlayerColor.white)){
            if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.king)) return pieceImage_w[0];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.queen)) return pieceImage_w[1];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.bishop)) return pieceImage_w[2];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.knight)) return pieceImage_w[3];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.rook)) return pieceImage_w[4];
            else if(piece.type.equals(PieceType.pawn)) return pieceImage_w[5];
            else return pieceImage_w[6];
        }
        else return pieceImage_w[6];
    }

    public final void initializeGui(){
        gui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();
        tools.setFloatable(false);
        gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Reset");
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                initiateBoard();
            }
        });

        tools.add(startButton);
        tools.addSeparator();
        tools.add(message);

        chessBoard = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 8));
        chessBoard.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        gui.add(chessBoard);
        ImageIcon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon(new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB));
        Insets buttonMargin = new Insets(0,0,0,0);
        for(int i=0; i<chessBoardSquares.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chessBoardSquares[i].length; j++) {
                JButton b = new JButton();
                b.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(i, j));
                b.setMargin(buttonMargin);
                b.setIcon(defaultIcon);
                if((j % 2 == 1 && i % 2 == 1)|| (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0)) b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                else b.setBackground(Color.gray);
                b.setOpaque(true);
                b.setBorderPainted(false);
                chessBoardSquares[j][i] = b;
            }
        }

        for (int i=0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < 8; j++) chessBoard.add(chessBoardSquares[j][i]);

        }
    }

    public final JComponent getGui() {
        return gui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ChessBoard cb = new ChessBoard();
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Chess");
                f.add(cb.getGui());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setResizable(false);
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
```

These are the functions I can use:

```
    class Piece{
        PlayerColor color;
        PieceType type;

        Piece(){
            color = PlayerColor.none;
            type = PieceType.none;
        }
        Piece(PlayerColor color, PieceType type){
            this.color = color;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }

    //Sets the icon on the chess board and updates the board status
    public void setIcon(int x, int y, Piece piece){
        chessBoardSquares[y][x].setIcon(getImageIcon(piece));
        chessBoardStatus[y][x] = piece;
    }
    
    //Gets the piece at a specific position on the chess board
    public Piece getIcon(int x, int y){
        return chessBoardStatus[y][x];
    }

    //Marks a position on the chess board with a pink color
    public void markPosition(int x, int y){
        chessBoardSquares[y][x].setBackground(Color.pink);
    }

    //Unmarks a position on the chess board, reverting it to its original color
    public void unmarkPosition(int x, int y){
        if((y % 2 == 1 && x % 2 == 1)|| (y % 2 == 0 && x % 2 == 0)) chessBoardSquares[y][x].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        else chessBoardSquares[y][x].setBackground(Color.gray);
    }

    //Updates the status label with a given message
    public void setStatus(String inpt){
        message.setText(inpt);
    }

    //Initiates the chess board with the initial piece setup
    public void initiateBoard(){
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++) setIcon(i, j, new Piece());
        }
        setIcon(0, 0, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.rook));
        setIcon(0, 1, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.knight));
        setIcon(0, 2, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.bishop));
        setIcon(0, 3, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.queen));
        setIcon(0, 4, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.king));
        setIcon(0, 5, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.bishop));
        setIcon(0, 6, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.knight));
        setIcon(0, 7, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.rook));
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            setIcon(1, i, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.pawn));
            setIcon(6, i, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.pawn));
        }
        setIcon(7, 0, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.rook));
        setIcon(7, 1, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.knight));
        setIcon(7, 2, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.bishop));
        setIcon(7, 3, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.queen));
        setIcon(7, 4, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.king));
        setIcon(7, 5, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.bishop));
        setIcon(7, 6, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.knight));
        setIcon(7, 7, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.rook));
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++) unmarkPosition(i, j);
        }
        onInitiateBoard();
    }
```

And here is the only section I should modify:

```
    enum MagicType {MARK, CHECK, CHECKMATE};
    private int selX, selY;
    private boolean check, checkmate, end;
    private int amountOfMoves = 0;

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        int x;
        int y;
        ButtonListener(int x, int y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
        
        //call when action is preformed
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    // Only modify here
            // (x, y) is where the click event occured
            
            if(!end) {
                if(isSelected()) {
                    if(isValidMove(selX, selY, x, y)) {
                        movePiece(selX, selY, x, y);

                        check = isCheck();

                        if(check == true) {
                            checkmate = isCheckmate();
                        }

                        updateBoardUI();
                        clearSelection();
                    } else {
                        setStatus("Invalid Move!");
                    }
                } else {
                    setStatus("Game Over!");
                }

            } else {
                setStatus("Game Over!");
            }
            
        }

        //is some piece selected on the board?
        private boolean isSelected() {
            return getIcon(selX,selY).color != PlayerColor.none; 
        }

        //calculates if the move is valid or not
        private boolean isValidMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
            Piece piece = getIcon(startX, startY);
            Piece targetPiece = getIcon(endX, endY);

            if(!isValidBoardPosition(endX, endY)) {
                setStatus("Invalid Board position!");
                return false;
            } else if(targetPiece.color == piece.color) {
                setStatus("You cannot attack your own pieces!");
                return false;
            }

            switch(piece.type) {
                case king:
                    return isValidKingMove(startX, startY, endX, endY);
                case queen:
                    return isValidQueenMove(startX, startY, endX, endY);
                case bishop:
                    return isValidBishopMove(startX, startY, endX, endY);
                case knight:
                    return isValidKnightMove(startX, startY, endX, endY);
                case rook:
                    return isValidRookMove(startX, startY, endX, endY);
                case pawn:
                    return isValidPawnMove(startX, startY, endX, endY);
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
       
        //moves selected piece to the give position
        private void movePiece(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
            Piece piece = getIcon(startX, startY);

            setIcon(endX, endY, piece);
            setIcon(startX, startY, new Piece());

            amountOfMoves++; 
        }

        // //checks if the clicked position is selectable
        // private boolean isSelectable(int x, int y) {
        //     Piece piece = getIcon(x, y);
        //     return piece.color == getCurrentPlayerColor() && piece.color != PlayerColor.none;
        // }

        //which color has its turn?
        private PlayerColor getCurrentPlayerColor() {
            if(amountOfMoves % 2 == 0 || amountOfMoves == 0) {
                return PlayerColor.black;
            } else {
                return PlayerColor.white;
            }
        }

        //checks if there is a check
        private boolean isCheck() {
            int kingX = -1, kingY = -1;

            //get position of the king of current player 
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (getIcon(i, j).type == PieceType.king && getIcon(i, j).color == getCurrentPlayerColor()) {
                        kingX = i;
                        kingY = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            //check if any of the opponents piece can attack the king 
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    Piece opponentPiece = getIcon(i, j);
                    if (opponentPiece.color != getCurrentPlayerColor()) {
                        if (isValidMove(i, j, kingX, kingY)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        //checks if there is a checkmate 
        private boolean isCheckmate() {
            int kingX = -1, kingY = -1;
            
            //get position of the king of current player
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    if (getIcon(i, j).type == PieceType.king && getIcon(i, j).color == getCurrentPlayerColor()) {
                        kingX = i;
                        kingY = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //
            for (int i = kingX - 1; i <= kingX + 1; i++) {
                for (int j = kingY - 1; j <= kingY + 1; j++) {
                    if (isValidMove(kingX, kingY, i, j) && !isCheck()) {
                        return false; // The king can escape check
                    }
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        //clears marked pieces
        private void clearSelection() {
            unmarkPosition(selX, selY);
            selX = -1;
            selY = -1;
        }

        //checks if the marked position is a valid Board position 
        private boolean isValidBoardPosition(int positionX, int positionY) {
            if(positionX < 0 || positionX > 7 || positionY < 0 || positionY > 7) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        //help function to determine if it is a valid Kind move
        private boolean isValidKingMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
            int diffX = Math.abs(endX - startX);
            int diffY = Math.abs(endY - startY);

            return (diffX <= 1 && diffY <= 1);
        }

        //help function to determine if it is a valid Queen move
        private boolean isValidQueenMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
            return isValidRookMove(startX, startY, endX, endY) || isValidBishopMove(startX, startY, endX, endY);
        }

        //help function to determine if it is a valid Bishop move
        private boolean isValidBishopMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
            int diffX = Math.abs(endX - startX);
            int diffY = Math.abs(endY - startY);
            return (diffX == diffY);
        }   

        //help function to determine if it is a valid Knight move
        private boolean isValidKnightMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
            int diffX = Math.abs(endX - startX);
            int diffY = Math.abs(endY - startY);

            return ((diffX == 2 && diffY == 1) || (diffX == 1 && diffY == 2));
        }

        //help function to determine if it is a valid Rook move
        private boolean isValidRookMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
            return (startX == endX) || (startY == endY);
        }   

        //help function to determine if it is a valid Pawn move
        private boolean isValidPawnMove(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {
            Piece pawn = getIcon(startX, startY);
            int direction = (pawn.color == PlayerColor.white) ? -1 : 1;
            int diffX = Math.abs(endX - startX);
            int diffY = endY - startY;

            //normal move
            if (diffX == 0 && diffY == direction && getIcon(endX, endY).color == PlayerColor.none) {
            return true;
            }

            //first move
            if (diffX == 0 && diffY == 2 * direction && startY == (pawn.color == PlayerColor.white ? 1 : 6)
                && getIcon(endX, endY - direction).color == PlayerColor.none
                && getIcon(endX, endY).color == PlayerColor.none) {
                
                    return true;
            }

            //capture diagonally
            if (diffX == 1 && diffY == direction && getIcon(endX, endY).color != PlayerColor.none) {
                return true;
            }
    
            //ToDo: pawn promotion??

            return false;
        }


    }

    void onInitiateBoard(){
        // Clear any previous selections
        //clearSelection();

        // Set up the initial chess board configuration
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                setIcon(i, j, new Piece());
            }
        }

        // Set up the black pieces
        setIcon(0, 0, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.rook));
        setIcon(0, 1, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.knight));
        setIcon(0, 2, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.bishop));
        setIcon(0, 3, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.queen));
        setIcon(0, 4, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.king));
        setIcon(0, 5, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.bishop));
        setIcon(0, 6, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.knight));
        setIcon(0, 7, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.rook));
    
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            setIcon(1, i, new Piece(PlayerColor.black, PieceType.pawn));
            setIcon(6, i, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.pawn));
        }

        // Set up the white pieces
        setIcon(7, 0, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.rook));
        setIcon(7, 1, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.knight));
        setIcon(7, 2, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.bishop));
        setIcon(7, 3, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.queen));
        setIcon(7, 4, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.king));
        setIcon(7, 5, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.bishop));
        setIcon(7, 6, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.knight));
        setIcon(7, 7, new Piece(PlayerColor.white, PieceType.rook));

        // Unmark all positions on the board
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                unmarkPosition(i, j);
            }
        }

        // Additional setup if needed

        // Update the UI
        updateBoardUI();
        
        // Set the initial message
        setStatus("Board reset. Start a new game!");

    }
//pieces on the board updated
private void updateBoardUI() {
    // Iterate through all board positions
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            // Get the piece at the current position
            Piece piece = getIcon(j, i);

            // Debug print
            System.out.println("Piece at (" + j + ", " + i + "): " + piece.color + " " + piece.type);

            // Update the button icon with the corresponding piece image
            chessBoardSquares[i][j].setIcon(getImageIcon(piece));

            // Update the background color based on the piece color
            if ((j % 2 == 1 && i % 2 == 1) || (j % 2 == 0 && i % 2 == 0)) {
                chessBoardSquares[i][j].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                chessBoardSquares[i][j].setBackground(Color.gray);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Always include a mention and a tag for your choice of Java GUI framework: Swing, JavaFX, SWT, Vaadin, etc.

Comment: I would change `b.setIcon(defaultIcon);` to something `b.setText("test");` - I suspect the images aren't loading

Comment: *pieceImage_b[0] = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("./img/king_b.png").getImage().getScaledInstance(64, 64, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));* Don't do it like that - it won't package properly. Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, I meant it won't distribute properly in a jar. That `ImageIcon` ctor is working on *files*, not resources. It should be the latter